# File Tabs and Tree in vim

Tags: multiple-files

I read this topic on [how to open multiple files and edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/how-can-i-edit-multiple-files-in-vim).

But there was a demo I saw where the user had multiple files open and showing as tabs in vim. How can I get that too ?

Also, there was a tree view like in other GUI editors.

I am using the default vim on macOS Mojave.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Generally, it is helpful to ask separate questions about separate issues. Also, while I normally discourage posting images of text, having an image to understand what you are looking at and what you are hoping to recreate would be helpful.

Comment: The demo was from Matteo Collina's screen on live.jsnation.com

Answer (score 2):

1. There are many commands in Vim. And I mean it. Some randomly popping in my mind are `:tabedit`, `:tab all` and <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. But I see no reason to re-tell here all that info from the standard docs you can read in `:h windows.txt`, `:h tabpage.txt` and such. I'm sure you can find what you need yourself.
2. The only "true" GUI tree widget I'm aware of, is Neovim-qt built-in (`:GuiTreeviewToggle` to toggle it). Otherwise it's a buffer emulating filesystem view suitable for both GUI and console. Such functionality usually provided by a dedicated plugin. There's one shipped with Vim installation (netrw), and also a few others you can download and install manually (the most popular is possibly [NERDTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree)).

Answer (score 0):

Vim does not create tabs for each buffer by defaul.
What you saw is most probably the [airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin, with a bit of configuration for the tabline.

Here's the minimum to get the airline's tabline:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this couple of days ago. You can open an explorer typing: `:Lexplore` (Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62764772/6093436) to learn the different ways to open a file). It is related with the netrw option that [Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26136/45033) mentioned. For tabs, you can check this [post](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/vim-tips-using-tabs/), it explains most of the commands for tabs with vim.